# Image in corner of tkinter window in python 3

Tags: python, image, window, tkinter

Is it possible to put a small image in tkinter window for ex. in the right corner of the window, if so how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a label, put an image in that label, then use [place](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) to put it precisely where you want. For example, you can use a relative x and y of 1.0 and an anchor of "se" to put it in the lower-right-hand corner.

Here is a contrived example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # a simple label, just to show there's something in the frame
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Example of using place")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        # we'll place this image in every corner...
        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(data='''
            R0lGODlhEAAQALMAAAAAAP//AP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            AAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQABAAQAQ3UMgpAKC4hm13uJnWgR
            TgceZJllw4pd2Xpagq0WfeYrD7\n2i5Yb+aJyVhFHAmnazE/z4tlSq0KIgA7\n
        ''')

        # ... by creating four label widgets ...
        self.nw = tk.Label(self, image=self.image)
        self.ne = tk.Label(self, image=self.image)
        self.sw = tk.Label(self, image=self.image)
        self.se = tk.Label(self, image=self.image)

        # ... and using place as the geometry manager
        self.nw.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, anchor="nw")
        self.ne.place(relx=1.0, rely=0.0, anchor="ne")
        self.sw.place(relx=0.0, rely=1.0, anchor="sw")
        self.se.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor="se")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_geometry("400x400")
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please write some simple program for this, I tried something but it didn't worked?

Comment: @TheQuiteStupidMan: I've added an example.